# Confused on the Euclidean formula yet AGAIN

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

I'm confused on what the formula is to get $s_2$ as well as $t_2$ as well as $s_3$ and $t_3$ ... I can't seem to crack it no matter how hard I try.By the way $s_0 = 1$ [image]

Comment: I think $s_2 = t_1 -(q_1 * s_1)$ but what about $s_3$?

Comment: is $s_3 = s_1 - (q_3 * q_2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$s_i=s_{i-2}-s_{i-1}\cdot q_{i-1}$

$t_i=t_{i-2}-t_{i-1}\cdot q_{i-1}$

Comment: Put $i=4$ so $s_4=s_2-s_3 \cdot q_3$.